# Logic Argument proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

$P(x) ⇒ Q(x)$

$\neg R(x) \lor \neg S(x)$

$\neg S(x) ⇒ \neg Q(x)$

$∴ P(x) ⇒ \neg R(x) $

I'm wondering how I can $P(x)$ instead of $Q(x)$. I tried using hypothetical reasoning such that we need $Q(x)$ so $S(x)$ but the question only gives $\neg S(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hypothetical reasoning is a good approach!

Ok, so let's assume $P(x)$

then by the first statement it follows that $Q(x)$.

We can do Contraposition on the third statement, giving us $Q(x) => S(x)$, so with $Q(x)$ We get $S(x)$.

By the second statement, we then have to get $\neg R(x)$, since we have $S(x)$, and thus you can't have that $\neg S(x)$.

So, assuming that $P(x)$ leads to $\neg R(x)$.

So, by conditional proof: $P(x) => \neg R(x)$.